# How to use c++ code to invoke and run one existed python file?

Tags: python, c++

I have one completed python program called email.py, this program was used to send a an email to a preset address. Is there a way that I can invoke this python file in c++ context? Like one c++ function that can invoke and run email.py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Python script from C++ and using its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962430/calling-python-script-from-c-and-using-its-output)

Comment: Perhaps stop in at the [help section (how to ask a question)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of stack overflow. It's a valuable resource for newer users like yourself. Also, you should try to search for the fix yourself next time. I did a short google and found thousands upon thousands of results to fix this exact issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use `system` in the `stdlin.h` library. This does not capture the output or anything regarding the exit status of the program. It simply invokes it as if you typed it on the command line

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  // Command as a string
  char* command = "python email.py";

  // Call it
  system(command);

  return 0;
}
```

This is a very simply solution. There are libraries such as as Boost that allows you to import Python into C++.

[How to import a function from python file by Boost.Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620134/how-to-import-a-function-from-python-file-by-boost-python)

Comment: hi, I tried your method, it said " module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP' "(mail = smtplib.SMTP is the code in my python file), so I think the location of my email.py file is wrong, where should I put my email.py file?

Comment: That's a problem with the Python code. Your code is probably importing the python module `smtplib`. It may be that your computer is running a newer or older version of python than that module requires, and something in the module has been moved. I've run across similar issues with the http libraries. But, I am not sure how to solve that. That has nothing to do with the C++ program running the Python program. Does the python program invoke successfully when run directly from command line?