# How do I import a class in a .py file from C++ using boost/python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, import, python-import

EDIT : Looks like I've messed up the solution from the second post, but it's still giving me an error after I corrected it.

Edit : I tried importing using a full path but it gave me a relative import error. I made another post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060211/attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package-with-boost-python)

the directories looks like this:

```
project
   |__ utilities
   |      |__ foo.py
   |
   |__ boost_extensions
   |      |__ myclass.cpp
   |      |__ myclass.so
   |
   |__ someotherstuff
   |      |__ bar.py      
   |
   |__ __main__.py
```

From bar.py I can just import something from foo.py like this:

```
from ..utilities.foo import Foo
```

However, from myclass.cpp I'm not sure how to import it. I've tried

```
boost::python::object mod = boost::python::import("..utilities.foo");
```

and

```
boost::python::object mod = boost::python::import("../utilities/foo.py");
```

both gave me an error module not found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.'
```

I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620134/how-to-import-a-function-from-python-file-by-boost-python) and tried the accepted answer but it did not work (same error as before):

```
boost::python::object mod;
void set_global(){
    try{
        setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
        Py_Initialize();
        mod = boost::python::import("..utilities.foo");
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `sys` and `os` however it still gave me an error (from an answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python) ):

```
    try{
        setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
        Py_Initialize();
        boost::python::object sys = import("sys");
        boost::python::object os = import("os");
        // sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Common'))
        // os.path.dirname(__file__)
        boost::python::object arg1 = os.attr("path").attr("dirname")("__file__");
        // os.path.join(arg1, '..', 'Common')
        boost::python::object arg2 = os.attr("path").attr("join")(arg1, "..", "Common");
        // sys.path.append(arg2)
        sys.attr("path").attr("append")(arg2);
        mod = boost::python::import("..utilities.foo");
    } catch(int e){
        cout << "import failed" << endl;
    }
```

error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.'
```

How am I supposed to import the module?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the full path? Also make the app tell you the current working directory.

Comment: I did, but it gave me a relative import error. I decided to make another post about it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060211/attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package-with-boost-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround: since Python modules are also PyObjects, I can load the module in Python and pass it to C++ as a variable. Here's the code:

The C++ file:

```
boost::python::object mod;
void set_global(boost::python::object foo_module){
    mod = foo_module;
    // this is for testing
    boost::python::object test = mod.attr("Foo")(new A(1,1,1), NULL, 12);
    A* a = extract<A*>(test.attr("_A")) ;
    cout << a->_x << endl << a->_y << endl << a->_z << endl;
}
```

In python (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061636/11627201)) :

```
from .utilities import foo as foo_module
set_globals(foo_module)
```

output:

```
1
1
1
```