# how can I import [.myfolder.pyfile] as [something else]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, boost-python

let's say I have

```
project
   |__ utilities
   |      |__ foo.py
   |
   |__ boost_extensions
   |      |__ myclass.cpp
   |      |__ myclass.so
   |
   |__ someotherstuff
   |      |__ bar.py      
   |
   |__ mylib.py
   |
   |__ __main__.py
```

Is it possible to do something like this in **main**.py

```
import .utilities.foo as Foo
# this function will pass Foo to C++ and initialize it to a global variable
initCppFunction(Foo)
```

I've tried this but it gives me an invalid syntax error (I'm trying to do this due to some problems with importing python modules from boost/python). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

from .utilities import foo as Foo

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that none of these folders have `__init__.py` in them, either the `project` folder nor `utilities` or `boost_extensions` or `someotherstuff`.

In order for Python to know that you want to be able to do imports it has to know that there's a whole grouping of code, called a package.  You do that by putting `__init__.py` files wherever you want to formalize and tell Python "this is a bundle of related code".

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

#### EDIT

The first answer also makes a good point, that you `from x.y import z` as the correct syntax.

#### EDIT 2

Krishnan is completely right.  The `__init__.py` files don't need to have anything in them.  You can put code in them if you want, but it's not required at all.

Comment: To clarify, these init files can be completely blank, to just tell Python that it is a module.