# Is it possibile to embed python libraries in C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

Is it possibile to use python libraries in C++ like selenium , django etc ....? If yes are there any docs that explain this well like fully embedding a python library in C++ not just some run script like PyRun_SimpleString() ???

Comment: What do you want to do with the libraries?

Comment: Use them in C++? seamlessly like in python

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do but if you want to use python libraries it would seem that your best option is to use python rather than c++

Comment: Many Python libraries are already written in C (or C++) and can be linked to your program.  Remember that Python requires an interpreter to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mix Python in a C++ project, a simple possibility is to include Boost in your project, and rely on the Boost.Python library which enables interoperability between Pyton and C++ (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html); This is basically a wrapper around the Python C API to make things easier, included into the well-known C++ Boost library.

In your case, you want to embed Python in C++, and Boost almost enables to do it without calling the Python C/ API: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html.
The use is pretty straightforward, you simply need to include `boost/python.hpp`, and embed the Python interpreter into your code snippet to call Python modules.

Without reinventing the wheel, here's a link to another SO question related to your topic with a nice answer which explains how to do it:
[How to import a function from python file by Boost.Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620134/how-to-import-a-function-from-python-file-by-boost-python).

Of course, you may not want to include Boost into your project (if you don't want to struggle installing it for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Python.h`, which is the C API for python. A brief description on how to do this is given here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820116/Embedding-Python-program-in-a-C-Cplusplus-code.

The python C API's documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html.

A suggestion, however: Whatever you're trying to do probably already has existing C++ libraries to do it. I'd advise against using a python library unless absolutely necessary. Or you could just stick to pure python.